# How to read a value from a select box with php?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

im using the cms contao and i got an overview page of some projects with 3 filters, one of them looks like this:

```
<select name="catitem_region_de" id="ctrl_filter_field_catitem_region_de" class="select" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"> 
   <option value="../cartitem_country/Deutschland" selected="selected">– Region –</option> 
   <option value="../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Europa">Europa</option> 
   <option value="../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Amerika">Amerika</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, when u select an option, the page refreshes with the selected filter.
My problem is, i want on every visit / refresh of the page, that a php script reads the value of the `selected="selected"` option. So that it looks like this:

If the option is "-Regio-", display content for region and if the content is anything else, display another content.

How can i do this with php?

thx

Comment: PHP or JavaScript ? Seems it can be done by JavaScript . For PHP, if you do not pass any value through GET / POST , you have still to rely on JavaScript to fetch selected value, or through a lot of DOM parsing.

Comment: I would say php, but im not sure.
The problem is, that i got some diverent php temples for e.g "-regio-" "Europa".
But i dont got a submit button on that page.

Comment: Why your not doing this with Ajax and PHP. on the basis of dropdown selection get data from ajax request and display on appropriate div.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would split your page in smaller pieces.

First part - Array of your links in JavaScript :

```
var links = { 0 : '', 
1 : '../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Europa',
2 : '../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Amerika' };
```

Second Part - Drop Down box:

```
<select name="catitem_region_de" id="ctrl_filter_field_catitem_region_de" class="select" onchange="changeDDB()"> 
  <option value="0" selected="selected">– Region –</option>
  <option value="1">Europa</option>
  <option value="2">Amerika</option>
</select>
```

Third Part - On Change JavaScript :

```
function changeDDB() {
  var idx = document.getElementById("ctrl_filter_field_catitem_region_de").selectedIndex;
  if(idx != 0) {
    window.location = links[idx];
  }
}
```

Comment: You meant to actually create a array? `var links = ['', '../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Europa', '../cartitem_partner_country/Deutschland/catitem_region_de/Amerika'];`

Comment: Thank you guys but the problem is, that the filtering is a feature from the cms.